# how to print each value in list returned from controller action in to each row of gsp table?

Tags: list, grails, action, row, gsp

I am returning a list of dates,list of size and list of months from controller action to gsp..i want each value in dates,size and months list  to be displayed in 3 different fields of each row.how to achieve it?

Advance thanks

laxmi.P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose `dlist` is the list of dates you are passing from the controller/action, then in gsp:

```
<table>
  <g:each in="${dlist}">
    <tr>Date: ${it}</tr>
  </g:each>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
  <g:each var="date" in="${dlist}">
    <p>date: ${date}</p>
  </g:each>
</table>
```

Enjoy

**UPDATE:**
To achieve this thing, I think it would be better to pass list of maps to gsp page, e.g

```
def index = {
  def data = [[date:"d1",size:'s1', month:'m1'],
              [date:'d2',size:'s2', month:'m2'],
              [date:'d3',size:'s3', month:'m3']]
  render(view:'/index',
         model:[data:data])

}
```

in gsp page:

```
<table>
  <g:each in="${data}">
    <tr><td>Date: ${it.date}, Size: ${it.size}, Month: ${it.month}</td></tr>
  </g:each>
</table>
```

**HTML view:**

```
Date: d1, Size: s1, Month: m1
Date: d2, Size: s2, Month: m2
Date: d3, Size: s3, Month: m3
```

Comment: but i have 3 lists date size and month passing from action i want each row to display each list value in 3 different td's..i used **<g:each in "${date},${size},${month}>**but it is'nt working

Comment: how can i use more than 1 list in each.

Answer (score 2):

`use <g:each> tag. Your <table> tag should be outside <g:each> and <tr> tags inside <g:each>`